# Wald Testing Bootstrapped Estimates in R

Tags: r, regression, anova, quantile, statistics-bootstrap

I've performed multiple regression (specifically quantile regression with multiple predictors using `quantreg` in R). I have estimated the standard error and confidence intervals based on bootstrapping the estimates. Now i want to test whether the estimates at different quantiles differ significantly from one another (Wald test would be preferable). How can i do this?

```
FML <- as.formula(outcome ~ VAR + c1 + c2 + c3)
quantiles <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)
q.Result <- rqs(FML, tau=quantiles, data, method="fn", na.action=na.omit)
q.Summary <- summary(Q.mod, se="boot", R=10000, bsmethod="mcmb",
                            covariance=TRUE)
```

From `q.Summary` i've extracted the bootstrapped (ie 10000) estimates (ie vector of 10000 bootstrapped B values).

Note: In reality I'm not especially interested comparing the estimates from all my covariates (in `FML`), I'm primarily interested comparing the estimates for `VAR`. What is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consulted with a colleague, and we resolved that estimates from different taus could be compared using Wald test as follows.

From object `rqs` produced by

```
q.Summary <- summary(Q.mod, se="boot", R=10000, bsmethod="mcmb", covariance=TRUE)
```

you extract the bootstrapped Beta values for variable of interest in this case `VAR`, the first covariate in `FML` for each tau

```
boot.Bs <- sapply(q.Summary, function (x) x[["B"]][,2])
B0 <- coef(summary(lm(FML, data)))[2,1] # Extract liner estimate data linear estimate
```

Then compute wald statistic and get pvalue with number of quantiles for degrees of freedom

```
Wald <- sum(apply(boot.Bs, 2, function (x) ((mean(x)-B0)^2)/var(x)))
Pvalue <- pchisq(Wald, ncol(boot.Bs), lower=FALSE)
```

You also want to verify that bootstrapped Betas are normally distributed, and if you're running many taus it can be cumbersome to check all those QQ plots so just sum them by row

```
qqnorm(apply(boot.Bs, 1, sum))
qqline(apply(boot.Bs, 1, sum), col = 2)
```

This seems to be working, and if anyone can think of anything wrong with my solution, please share